# Why does increasing the number of values in an IN statement in Cosmos return fewer (zero) results?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a query,

```
SELECT c FROM c JOIN a IN c.some_id WHERE a IN ("some_value")
```

This returns 1 document (expected)

I write another query,

```
SELECT c FROM c JOIN a IN c.some_id WHERE a IN ("some_value", "another_value")
```

This returns 0 values (unexpected)

Why is this?

Comment: I didn't reproduce your issue , would you please post your sample document?

Comment: How are you executing the queries? Could it be you are given a continuation token?

Comment: The query is executed in document explorer (and the Python API). There is only one result, so I am not sure how a continuation token would come in to play.

Comment: @MaxCandocia What's the sample document?

Comment: This issue is specific to a collection that I have. It works in other collections I have, but not all of them. I am not sure that it's the specific documents that are the issue.